# How to read the shared data in the Multithreading program efficiently?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, thread-safety, scheduled-tasks

I have a background thread which is updating one of my class variables. I am using `ScheduledExecutorService` which runs every 10 minutes. Below is my background thread code -

What my below class does is, it will run every 10 minutes and parse the data coming from the URL and store it in a variable.

```
public class ScheduledCall {

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void startScheduleTask() {

        final ScheduledFuture<?> taskHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            callServers();
                        } catch(Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace(); //or loggger would be better
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private void callServers() {
        String url = "url";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        parseResponse(response);

    }

    private void parseResponse(String response) {
        //...       
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> primaryTables = null;

        //...

        // store the data in ClientData variables which can be
        // used by other threads
        ClientData.setHostToNodesTable(primaryTables);   

    }
}
```

After parsing the data coming from the URL, it will store the result in my class `ClientData` in its variables by using its setters. Below is my `ClientData class`.

```
public class ClientData {

    private static ConcurrentMap<String, Map<Integer, String>> hostToNodesTable = null;

    // setters and getters here

}
```

Now the interesting part comes. I have a separate Multithread program which is running in the same application as the above background thread code. And that multithreading program has to access the above fields. I am using Future and Callable task here in my below multithreading program which tries to access `hostToNodesTable` value from its getter -

```
public class ClientTask implements Callable<String> {

    private String userId = null;

    public ClientTask(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

    //.....

    String hostname = ClientData.getHostToNodesTable("some_string").get(some_number);

    //....

    }   
}
```

Now I know this is not thread safe bcoz it might be possible when background thread is updating the map, my other thread is trying to retrieve the value from its. How do I make this thread safe? And is there any other problem as well which I should know?

Comment: concurrentmap implementations are thread safe with happens-before contract. What is your objective, what do you want to do. concurrent maps have great scalabitlity too. What is the problem that you might face you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The a simple solution IMHO is to use an AtomicReference.

```
private static final AtomicReference<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>> hostToNodesTable 
       = new AtomicReference<>();

static Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> getTable() {
     return hostToNodesTable.get();
}


static void setTable(Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> map) {
     hostToNodesTable.set(map);
}
```

This way your background thread never alters the table. It just creates a new HashMap, builds it and when finished replaces the whole thing.

For the readers they can call getTable() and use the map as long as they like but won't see any changes until getTable() is called again.

Since you are replacing the whole map anyway (no need to remove entries), this is much more efficient than using a ConcurrentHashMap.

---

As Holger points out, this is just wrapping a `volatile` reference, and a simpler solution is to just use such a volatile field.  If you do this, you have to remember to take a local copy (assign it to a local variable) so that is you reference it multiple times it won't change while you are using it.

Comment: No, the simplest solution is to use a `volatile` variable. If you don't use (like in the question) operations with an atomic set-and-get semantic, `AtomicReference` offers no benefit over a `volatile` variable. In fact, it is a wrapped `volatile` variable, with additional operations which are not used here.